# RoR trim string

Tags: ruby-on-rails

this gives
`abcdefghi`

but I want it to be

if length is greater than 5 then
`abcde...`

if less than 5 then
`abcde`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rails has a built-in view helper for this:

```
<%= truncate(user.name, :length => 5) %>
```

- [truncate helper API documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#M002277)

Comment: +1 - every time I start to code something on my own, it is already there.

Comment: Yeah, knowing what's already available is a big part of knowing Rails (or any framework/API).